# Correct TabBar and NavBar relationship/setup

Tags: ios

I need a `Tab Bar Controller` and a `Nav Bar Controller` (for the tabs).  What is the correct setup?

I currently have a `Tab Bar Controller` where each tab leads to a separate `Nav Bar Controller` that leads to the VC.  Is this the correct setup?  Or is there a preferred method to have a tab bar that leads to a single nav bar that controls the VC's (for each tab)?  Is it even possible, or does it just lead to a lot of complications?

Comment: did you do this by storyboard or programatically?

Comment: I created it in the Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by one Navigation controller:

see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/llxpM.jpg

***Detail description:***

*Navigation and Tab Bar*

1. **NavigationController** -> check mark to **Is Initial View Controller**
2. **TabBarController** -> Relationship segue as **root View Controller**

*Both Tabs*

3. **FisrtTabViewController**-> Relationship segue as  **View Controllers**
4. **SecondTabViewController**-> Relationship segue as  **View Controllers**

*Both Tabs Details*

5. **FisrtTabDetailViewController**-> Action segue  **Show**
6. **SecondTabDetailViewController**-> Action segue **Show**

Comment: Will have a look tomorrow and test, thanks. Is IT The preferred way?

Comment: I appreciate your help, I really do, but I have run into a number of issues with having the Tab Controller inside a Nav Controller (navigationItem.title on first Tabviews for one). It is impossible to set.

From UITabBarController Class Reference: Unlike other view controllers, **a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.**